# Reading selected checkboxes as int

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I have a database generated model with an int property (not list or anything fancy).
Trying to map this property to 2 checkboxes that represent "contact method".

1. text, 2. email, or both, and read this as a single number in the DB column 1, 2 or 3 for both.

Tried setting the values in regular html inputs and using @html.checkboxfor(x => x.boolproperty), what I can't figure out is how to get a value from both checkboxes.

Comment: Please mark the answer as "answered" if it is an good answer for your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x` is your viewmodel and `boolproperty` is a field of the viewmodel.
If you do the same as you do right now for the second checkbox aswel (so create a second field in the viewmodel for that) and then check in the controller:

```
int number = 0;
if (boolproperty && !boolproperty2)
{
 number = 1;
}
else if (!boolproperty && boolproperty2)
{
 number = 2;
}
else if (boolproperty && boolproperty2)
{
 number = 3;
}
```

Comment: This is sort of what I was looking for to make this work, appreciated.